# Is there a way to keep a file stream entierly in memory?

Tags: c++, systemd-journald

I want to extract logs from journald on a embedded device running a yocto build. My current solution is using the sd-journal api to iteratively fetch all journal entries and sticking them into a fstream object. This object is then compressed using zlib, and finally uploaded to my ftp server using libcurl.

After an upload I need to remove the two files I have created: the original raw journal log (which can be up to 12 MB) and the compressed log. Is there a more pragmatic way for uploading entries from journald than I am doing here? Is it possible to create a file stream in memory, without it being written to disk?

Comment: How about `std::ostringstream`? But are you sure that you can fit all the data of the journal as a single contiguous chunk of memory? Embedded systems aren't know for having plenty of memory... :)

Comment: Optionally, a vector of strings, where each string might be created using `std::ostringstream`? Then you won't need one single large chunk of memory for all the data.

Comment: Boost iostreams might help https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html

Comment: Yes, rather than trying to keep a filestream in memory, I'd read directly from the journal file, then send the data through an iostream with compression, and transmission over TCP. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39918811/179910

Comment: Letting the embedded device do all the heavy lifting (compressing etc) seems to be a bit heavy. I would begin by unit testing as much as your code as possible, for all the code that is unit tested remove the logs. Only log the bare minumum, logs should be used to diagnose the system (e.g. changing inputs), logs should not be used to verify the correct working of your business logic. Non-essential logging (for debugging) you can also emit by serial bus,sockets,or RPC calls (gRPC) and then record the logs remotely. Summary : reduce the size of what you log to the bare minimum

Comment: I've not **yet** added boost to my system yet. If I were to do so now it would be because I had not other way. I've added guards to journalctl to rotate the journal content if the size gets larger than 12MB (which seems to occur every other day or so). I'll give the basic `std::ostringstream` approach a whirl.

Comment: Note that zlib and friends are designed to support incremental compression anyway, so you can just feed them blocks of data as you read it. The larger problem is the FTP server at the other end. Avoid FTP like the plague and use something that supports streaming writes instead.